# converting foreach to LINQ while writing to Logger or Console

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following piece of foreach code how do I write it as a LINQ

```
foreach(var error in ex.Errors)
{
   Logger.Error("Field {0} has an error : {1}. for SSN {2}",error.FieldName,    error.Message, error.SSN);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to write it in LINQ?

Comment: No need for LINQ here

Comment: Linq isn't for side effects. That's what loops are for which you already have.

Comment: wondering if it was worth it to write as LINQ. From the comments I see its not.

Comment: if you really want to avoid using `foreach` here, you could use the `List<T>.ForEach(Action<T>)` to do the same, it is more obscure though

Comment: You may want to read this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ is for producing results, such as new sequences and aggregates. It is *not* a good fit for producing side effects, such as log outputs.

The `foreach` loop in your code is a perfectly acceptable, very readable solution. If you would like to get rid of it anyway, you could use [`List.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which takes an `Action<T>`:

```
ex.Errors.ForEach(
    error => Logger.Error(
        "Field {0} has an error : {1}. for SSN {2}"
    ,   error.FieldName
    ,    error.Message
    ,   error.SSN);
);
```

Comment: not always as clear as using a dedicated `foreach` loop, but I have used this before myself.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would not do this, but if you really want to use LINQ here, there are two options:

```
ex.Errors.ForEach(error => Logger.Error("Field {0} has an error : {1}. for SSN {2}", error.FieldName, error.Message, error.SSN));
```

or

```
Logger.Error(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    ex.Errors.Select(error => 
        string.Format("Field {0} has an error : {1}. for SSN {2}", error.FieldName, error.Message, error.SSN))));
```

But the second one depends a little on how your `Logger.Error` is implemented and if it's ok to join the strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to list and use [ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
ex.Errors.ToList().ForEach(error =>
{
    Logger.Error("Field {0} has an error : {1}. for SSN {2}", error.FieldName, error.Message, error.SSN);
});
```

Alternatively, write your own ForEach extension method:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach(T item in enumeration)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```

But in this case is probably better don't using Linq.